# Dirichlet Theorem Expansion to power series

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, power-series, dirichlet-series

I am nearly complete in my understanding of this beautiful theorem of Dirichlet. On page 34 of Davenports book (Multiplicative number theory) the following breakdown is present and I do not understand where the expansion of powers comes in

\begin{equation}
    \psi(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{s}}
\end{equation}
 Since $\psi(s)$ is analytic for $\sigma> \frac{1}{2}$, it has expansion in powers of s-2 with radius of convergence at least $\frac{3}{2}$. This power series is
 \begin{equation}
     \psi(s) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!}\psi^{(m)}(2)(s-2)^m
 \end{equation}
The value for $\psi^{(m)}(2)$ can be obtained from the Dirichlet series in Equation (29) from  and we get:
\begin{equation}
    \psi^{(m)}(2) = (-1)^m \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n (\text{log}n)^m n^{-2}=(-1)^m b_m
\end{equation}
where $b_m > 0$. So we have
\begin{equation}
     \psi(s) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!} b_m (2-s)^m
\end{equation}
and this holds for $|s-2|<\frac{3}{2}$. If $\frac{1}{2}<s<2$ and since all terms are non negative we have $$\psi(s) \geq \psi(2) \geq 1$$ and this contradicts the fact that $\psi(s) \to 0$ ````

Does the second line have something to do with Cauchy's integral formula? Can someone explain to me the 2nd step, and also the very last line?

Comment: You meant $a_n\ge 0$. If some $a_n> 0,n> 1$ then $s\in (1/2,2)$ implies that $\psi(s) > \psi(2) > 0$ just by looking at the Dirichlet series whose every term is decreasing.